# User submits keyword via a form; how can I get the 'keyword' part of a search URL to get modified in the page?

Tags: javascript, forms, url, onclick

I have a page with a number of URLs on it that go to saved searches. I would like to add a text form field that users can add a keyword to those URLs. Currently I'm using this javascript in the header:

```
function change_text(){
    var changetext = document.getElementById("newtext").value;
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = changetext;
}
```

And this in the body:

```
   <a href="http://google.com/search?q=javascript%20url<span id="text">%20</span>">Saved Search</a>
   <input type="text" id="newtext"><input type="button" value="Press to change URL!"language="javascript" onClick="change_text()">
```

But the 'span' tag gets added to the URL and breaks it. Is there any simple way users can update the URL without requiring a webserver?

Comment: This is no valid html. URLs may not contain tags. You can do what you want via JavaScript by setting the href of the anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<a href='http://google.com/search?q='>Google</a>
<br>
<a href='http://yahoo.com/sd?='>Yahoo</a>
<br>
<input id='newLink'><input type="button" value="Press to change URLs!" onClick="change_text()">
<script>
a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
href = new Array()
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
a.id='link'+i;
href.push(a[i].href);
}

function change_text(){
keyword = document.getElementById('newLink').value;
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
a[i].href = href[i]+keyword;
}

}

</script>
```

Comment: Probably you should concat the string to make a valid search url, like `document.getElementById('link').href = "http://google.com/search?q=" + newLink`.

Comment: Yeah, I'd misinterpreted the question. Just added the concatenation.

Comment: You should call `encodeURIComponent` on the input value to make sure that the URL will be escaped.

Comment: Well played, sir. Since original is only being set once, change_text will always overwrite with the correct url. +1

Comment: @Digital Yeah, I don't know why I didn't originally. I'll add it now.

Comment: Brilliant; that works for the first URL on the page. Is there a line I need to add to get it to loop through the rest of the URLs on the page?

Comment: @Adam, so you mean, the input would change the URL for all the a tags? Or do you mean they get their own input field to change it?

Comment: Indeed, the input would change the URL for all the <a> tags. So I have 81 differently configured saved searches on a page and an 'add keyword' form. If a user puts 'Mumbai' into the <input> and clicks 'Add keyword' it should append that keyword to every URL so when the user clicks on it it will take them to the search results filtered to that keyword. Hope that makes sense; you've done a great job getting me to here, thanks Amaan!

Comment: @Amaan Cheval Are you sure that you want to change *every* a's href? I would give all search <a>s the same class and use document.getElementsByClassName(), so you will only change the relevant links.

Comment: @Martin That's exactly what I was wondering, but I'm sure Adam can manage doing that. If not, he could always just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something more like:

```
  <a id=text href="http://google.com/search?q=javascript%20url#">Saved Search</a>


function change_text(){
    var changetext = document.getElementById("newtext").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("text")
    text.attr("href", text.attr("href").replace("#", changetext);
}
```

That is, replacing the entire URL. You may have to verify that there is somethign other than just # on the search page ( # is only an example, you could use any appropriate character.)